# I am trying to only allow the SKSpritenode to jump one time but having issue with velocity

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I am currently using the WizardCharacter.physicsbody.velocity.dy, and checking if it is equal to 0. I do not want the character to be able to jump in air. The issue I am facing is, my character is resting and he is not moving and the velocity of y is going from 0 to 1 while not doing any actions to the character. I am not sure why this is happening, I am using SpriteKit and SceneKit. I have provided my code, as well a picture for what the console is printing out.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        print("\(String(describing: wizardCharacter.physicsBody?.velocity.dy))")
        cameraNode.position.x = wizardCharacter.position.x
        if wizardCharacter.action(forKey: "wizardRun") == nil {
            wizardCharacter.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "wizard_1_attack-b_001")
        }
if upArrow.contains(pointTouched)
            {
                if wizardCharacter.physicsBody?.velocity.dy == 0 && isJumping == true {
                upArrow.alpha = 0.5
                jumpWizard(forTheKey: "jumped")
                jumpWizardAnimation(fortheKey: "jumpedAnimation")
                }
            }
```

[image: Velocity of Character in y]

Comment: do you see that e-07?  that means you are 7 decimal places over.  the real number is 0.00000013969...  which is still practically 0

Comment: @Knight0fDragon but sometimes since the velocity.dy is not equal to exactly 0, I cant click the jump button...

Comment: That is the problem with float